# Can you get punished for cheating on a single player game on steam?

Tags: steam, cheats

I have some single player games that I want to skip the grind part and go straight to the end game content. Could I get VAC if the game has no online content?

For example, I got [heat-signature](/questions/tagged/heat-signature) and wanted to get more money ingame.

However, the new Shadow of War (releasing on Oct. 10) will have microtransactions to buy chests. The game being offline (maybe with online checks), could I get banned?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Games on Steam should tell you on their store page if VAC is enabled.  CSGO for example shows this:

[image: CSGO]

If you don't see this, then you likely won't get VAC banned.  Looking at Heat Signature, it does not appear to have VAC enabled.

Comment: I was really specific on the question about VAC, but you know of any other thing that could lock me out of a single player game? (Like a Warner Bros lock)

Comment: @Moacir can't say for sure since there doesn't appear to be information available for this game, but looking at the game itself, I'm going to say no.

Comment: Thank you. Just fyi, I just didn't accept your answer because I need to wait a bit.

Comment: @Moacir Typically anti-cheat is built into the game, and it's mostly to combat those who have pirated the game. It's up to the devs, but for Heat Signature, it still doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Of note, it seems like non-VAC enabled games can be affected by VAC status. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FG6fo34JOAk

Comment: @Kaizerwolf What does Anti Cheat got to do with pirating games?

Comment: @MichaelPittino The same techniques which are used for cheating (patching the game executable, memory editing, meddling with network traffic...) can also be used for circumventing DRM. That means an anti-cheat tool often also doubles as a DRM tool and vice versa.

Comment: Can you name one AC that does that? Would be interesting, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelPittino I recall an older GTA game that if you pirated it, you could play for about 20 minutes before getting permanently locked in your apartment. Could be remembering wrong, but it's something along those lines.

Comment: Some games do other things, such as in Serious Sam, pirated versions of the game would spawn an invincible pink scorpion that would constantly follow and attack you (pretty sure there was a question on here that discussed that somewhere)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Oh, interesting. But in an online game, the Anti Cheat usually doesn't care about pirated versions, since they can't connect to the game server anyway.

Answer (score 5):

There are some games that "punish" the player if they cheat (look at [Stanley's Parable](https://youtu.be/S1yMhuoAxxc?t=40s)), but if it's a singleplayer game there is no reason for contacting the server to check if your files are legit and ban you if not. Unless that there is a online leaderboard or something like that.

If you are still unsure planning on cheat don't try to use any online feature of the game. You can even block the game from contacting the internet to be sure.

Comment: With Stanley's Parable, it seems like it'd be just one more play path.

Comment: In Stanley Parable it's just one of the countless meta-jokes the "game" consists of. But there are lots of other examples of games which disable achievements or scoreboards when you use cheats. These, however, usually apply to those cheatcodes the developers built into the game intentionally, not 3rd party cheat tools and hacks.